# What does the output from CTRL+N in Windows Command Prompt mean?

Tags: windows, command-line

In the Microsoft Windows Command Prompt (Win7), what does the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> do?

I get the following output:

```
C:\Users\pbarney>^N
'' ␋_ ┼¯├ _␊␌¯±┼␋≥␊␍ ▒_ ▒┼ ␋┼├␊_┼▒┌ ¯_ ␊│├␊_┼▒┌ ␌¯└└▒┼␍,
¯▬␊_▒␉┌␊ ▬_¯±_▒└ ¯_ ␉▒├␌␤ °␋┌␊.
```

I recognize that the preceding line is similar in length to the following message when you type an invalid command:

```
'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm curious why it does this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts scroll down for Command line shortcuts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASCII standard has two code points, [SHIFT OUT *and* SHIFT IN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_Out_and_Shift_In_characters) that switch between two different modes.

Historically, these were black and red typewriter ribbon. The instance you see is a VT100 compatible terminal emulator, which uses these to switch between regular text and line drawing characters. This is a simple data compression standard, in which bit 7 of each character is set from the current shift state rather than transferred, which gives a slight speed boost over a serial link.

Comment: I see now! Ctrl+N is shift out, and Ctrl+O is shift in, so ^Ntest^Otest shows this: ├␊_├test

Answer (score 16):

It is a "not recognized as an internal or.... " message, but it seems that it isn't displaying correctly. Be sure that command prompt fonts are set to raster.

If I paste the output here, I get the same scrambled characters you do, presumably due to character encoding. Here's the cmd output as a screenshot:

[image]

It seems as if the symbol is a UTF-8 symbol, since N++ won't render it correctly in ANSI, but will in UTF-8

```
U+266B  ♫   e2 99 ab    BEAMED EIGHTH NOTES
```

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9728

You will notice that pressing Ctrl and other letters will produce other symbols, such as the spades symbol for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Comment: It occurs for me with raster fonts as well, but the thing I'm most curious about is WHY the output is in a different character coding.

Comment: This does a better job at explaining it than I can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: Do you know Ctrl + G causes my PC to beep?

Comment: Ctrl + G is the "BELL" symbol, originally meant to send an audible notification beep on old terminals. Still works in the command prompt!